# Automatically install libraries

Tags: python, linux, installation, automation, libraries

Even if i risk some negative votes, i want to ask you about a strategy to do some automaticaaly installations of libraries and packages. I tested and **worked great** the strategy of finding all libraries from `pip freeze` and attaching them into a `file.txt` . After that, i used `pip install -r file.txt`. So far,so good. But what cand you do when you want to gradually add libraries and don't want to write manually in the `file.txt`,but simply have a code that reads the new library,eventually use the `subprocess` and installs it automatically? The purpose behind this question is to make the code to work at its fullest only when compiling the program (one single human action,when you run the code, it reads the new libraries and installs it automatically,without to write them in the `file.txt`) . Any ideas are apreciated,thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have all of the parts in place. Why not just write a bash script that runs every day to call `pip freeze`, put it in the txt file, and update everything?

Then run the script as often as you want with `crontab`

Comment: I searched for the crontab and it is not what i'm looking for. When told about automation, i meant about to install all the needed libraries with a single human action (only when you run the code, the libraries are automatically installed ). Thank you anyway for your intervention.